# Both right and left aligned icons in AppBar with material-ui next

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If I have an `AppBar`, how can I make it so one group of icons plus the logo is on the left, and another group of icons are on the right of it?

Ex:

- Left: (from left to right)  1 menu icon, logo
- Right: (from right to left) 1 menu icon, 1 save icon, 1 edit icon

AppBar component:

```
<AppBar
            className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
                [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                [classes[`appBarShift-left`]]: open,
                [classes[`appBarShift-right`]]: !tools,
            })}
            position='static'
        >
            <Toolbar className={classNames(classes.topBar)}>
                <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open drawer"
                    onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
                    className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
                >
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" noWrap>React App</Typography>
                <IconButton
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="open tool drawer"
                    onClick={this.handleToolDrawerToggle}
                    className={classNames(classes.menuButton)}
                >
                    <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
```

Comment: do you still need help with this?

Comment: So far the only option I found was having an element in between two toolsbars that flex stretch across the entire thing, but that doesn't always work.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Answer (score 67):

You can use flexbox to control the alignment of elements in the toolbar...

One option is to add `flex: 1` to the logo element. It will expand to fill the available space in container. All the elements after logo will be aligned to the right.

OR

Use `margin-left: auto` to align the second group of buttons to the right side of the flex container.

[Here is a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-appbar-example)

```js
const styles = {
  // this group of buttons will be aligned to the right side
  toolbarButtons: {
    marginLeft: 'auto',
  },
};

const Demo = ({ classes }) => (
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      <IconButton color="inherit">
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">Title</Typography>
      <div className={classes.toolbarButtons}>
        <IconButton color="inherit"><EditIcon /></IconButton>
        <IconButton color="inherit"><SaveIcon /></IconButton>
        <IconButton color="inherit"><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
);
```

Answer (score 29):

I know it's been a while since you asked the question, I would like to provide an alternative solution. Add Box tag (similar to flexbox in CSS)  around the components on the left and adjust the `flexGrow` attribute and it works for me:

```
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

{/* BEFORE APPBAR*/}

<AppBar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Box display='flex' flexGrow={1}>
            {/* whatever is on the left side */}
        </Box>
        {/* whatever is on the right side */}
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>

{/* AFTER APPBAR*/}
```

Comment: ...as Luke already mentioned in his first solution.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using inline css inside Toolbar component itself, it worked for me;
`<Toolbar style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:"space-between", width:'100%'}}>`

Comment: just <Toolbar style={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}> works, width: 100% pushes button half off the parent div for me.